# How do I set the CODI project stage?

Tags: codi

I found this [wiki page](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/EXTCDI/Core+Usage#CoreUsage-Activation) through a nabble posting, but I can't make sense of it.  In my JSF application, how do I tell CODI that I want to be running in development mode?   Is there a web.xml setting or do I have to use an annotation somewhere?

Much thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/EXTCDI/Core+Usage#CoreUsage-EnvironmentConfigOptions Web.xml settings aren't supported see: "Static configuration files like web.xml and property files aren't supported by default because ..."

Comment: do you have an example of this, the documentation is too terse for me to comprehend. Thanks.

Comment: I would contact the project team. They should add something to the Wiki if you miss something.

Comment: I did contact the project team, unfortunately the response was concise to the point of not being comprehensible!

Comment: I can't see your E-Mail on their mailing list.

Comment: I have more than one email address. More worrying is the fact that you could find out what it is on here, I'd assumed that only I could see it. As it happens my question was specific to startup logging, close though: http://old.nabble.com/CODI---turn-off-startup-config-logging--td32898132.html#a32904409

Comment: The mailing lists are public. So what are you worrying about? Thank you for the link, but that's a different topic.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's been a couple of months since you asked the question, but I achieve this by setting javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE=Development as a system property when running in my dev environment.
CODI doesn't pick it up from web.xml, but does test the system property.

Comment: You see the reason in my answer.